java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Error de sintaxis: Encountered "USER" and "ORDER"
I was doing a project on NetBeans, using GlassFish and JDBC. I was working on some views using JSP and my project suddenly crashed. I tried searching for a solution but can't get to solve it. This is the error that I get:
EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 4.0.2.v202306161219|#]
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 4.0.2.v202306161219): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Error de sintaxis: Encountered "USER" at line 1, column 14.
Error Code: 30000
Call: CREATE TABLE USER (IDUSER BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, ADDRESS VARCHAR(255), EMAIL VARCHAR(255), NAME VARCHAR(255), PASSWORD VARCHAR(255), PHONE INTEGER, ROL VARCHAR(255), USERNAME VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (IDUSER))
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE USER (IDUSER BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, ADDRESS VARCHAR(255), EMAIL VARCHAR(255), NAME VARCHAR(255), PASSWORD VARCHAR(255), PHONE INTEGER, ROL VARCHAR(255), USERNAME VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (IDUSER))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2048)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:913)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3308)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1841)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1823)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1773)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.priviledgedExecuteNonSelectingCall(AbstractSession.java:5055)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.DatabaseObjectDefinition.createOnDatabase(DatabaseObjectDefinition.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.SchemaManager.createObject(SchemaManager.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.TableCreator.createTables(TableCreator.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.TableCreator.createTables(TableCreator.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.TableCreator.createTables(TableCreator.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.SchemaManager.createDefaultTables(SchemaManager.java:1034)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.generateDefaultTables(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeDDLToDatabase(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:4731)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeMetadataDDLToDatabase(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:4798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeDDL(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:4697)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeDDL(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:4570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:222)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:545)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:325)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:984)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:257)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:471)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:569)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:453)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:564)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:587)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:453)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:586)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1477)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:536)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:425)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Error de sintaxis: Encountered "USER" at line 1, column 14.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(SqlException.java:325)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.prepareStatement(ClientConnection.java:448)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.prepareStatement(ConnectionHolder.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1750)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1697)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:630)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Error de sintaxis: Encountered "USER" at line 1, column 14.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeSqlca(ClientStatement.java:2116)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(NetStatementReply.java:579)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(NetStatementReply.java:145)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(NetStatementReply.java:54)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(StatementReply.java:41)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(NetStatement.java:156)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(ClientStatement.java:1702)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1914)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1977)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.prepare(ClientPreparedStatement.java:315)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.prepareStatementX(ClientConnection.java:1956)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.prepareStatement(ClientConnection.java:435)
    ... 80 more
|#]
  Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 4.0.2.v202306161219): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Error de sintaxis: Encountered "ORDER" at line 1, column 14.
Error Code: 30000
Call: CREATE TABLE ORDER (IDORDER BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, DATE TIMESTAMP, STATE VARCHAR(255), TOTAL FLOAT, idUser BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (IDORDER))
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE ORDER (IDORDER BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, DATE TIMESTAMP, STATE VARCHAR(255), TOTAL FLOAT, idUser BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (IDORDER))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2048)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:913)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3308)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1841)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1823)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1773)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.priviledgedExecuteNonSelectingCall(AbstractSession.java:5055)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.DatabaseObjectDefinition.createOnDatabase(DatabaseObjectDefinition.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.SchemaManager.createObject(SchemaManager.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.TableCreator.createTables(TableCreator.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.TableCreator.createTables(TableCreator.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.TableCreator.createTables(TableCreator.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.SchemaManager.createDefaultTables(SchemaManager.java:1034)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.generateDefaultTables(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeDDLToDatabase(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:4731)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeMetadataDDLToDatabase(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:4798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeDDL(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:4697)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeDDL(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:4570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:222)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:545)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:325)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:984)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:257)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:471)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:569)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:453)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:564)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:587)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:453)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:586)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1477)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:536)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:425)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Error de sintaxis: Encountered "ORDER" at line 1, column 14.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(SqlException.java:325)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.prepareStatement(ClientConnection.java:448)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.prepareStatement(ConnectionHolder.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1750)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1697)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:630)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Error de sintaxis: Encountered "ORDER" at line 1, column 14.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeSqlca(ClientStatement.java:2116)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(NetStatementReply.java:579)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(NetStatementReply.java:145)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(NetStatementReply.java:54)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(StatementReply.java:41)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(NetStatement.java:156)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(ClientStatement.java:1702)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1914)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1977)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.prepare(ClientPreparedStatement.java:315)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.prepareStatementX(ClientConnection.java:1956)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.prepareStatement(ClientConnection.java:435)
    ... 80 more
|#]
  Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 4.0.2.v202306161219): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Error de sintaxis: Encountered "ORDER" at line 1, column 13.
Error Code: 30000
Call: ALTER TABLE ORDER ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ORDER_idUser FOREIGN KEY (idUser) REFERENCES USER (IDUSER)
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="ALTER TABLE ORDER ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ORDER_idUser FOREIGN KEY (idUser) REFERENCES USER (IDUSER)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:569)
    at 

And then
Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDI is not available
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:116)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:533)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:257)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:471)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:569)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:453)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:564)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:587)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:453)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:586)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1477)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)

Keep in mind, I'm a first year college student so I'm not experienced at all.
Now I get this error:

/index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

I looked it up and some people said it was because of the structure of the project, here's mine:

C:.
│   build.xml
│
├───build
│   ├───empty
│   ├───generated-sources
│   │   └───ap-source-output
│   └───web
│       │   gfv700ee10.dpf
│       │   index.html
│       │
│       ├───css
│       │       main.css
│       │
│       ├───js
│       │       functions.js
│       │
│       ├───META-INF
│       │       MANIFEST.MF
│       │
│       └───WEB-INF
│           │   glassfish-web.xml
│           │
│           ├───classes
│           │   │   .netbeans_automatic_build
│           │   │   .netbeans_update_resources
│           │   │
│           │   ├───daw
│           │   │   ├───controllers
│           │   │   │       ProductController.class
│           │   │   │
│           │   │   └───model
│           │   │           Product.class
│           │   │
│           │   └───META-INF
│           │           persistence.xml
│           │
│           └───views
│                   error.jsp
│                   formProduct.jsp
│                   products.jsp
│
├───nbproject
│   │   ant-deploy.xml
│   │   build-impl.xml
│   │   genfiles.properties
│   │   project.properties
│   │   project.xml
│   │
│   └───private
│           private.properties
│           private.xml
│
├───setup
│       glassfish-resources.xml
│
├───src
│   ├───conf
│   │       MANIFEST.MF
│   │       persistence.xml
│   │
│   └───java
│       └───daw
│           ├───controllers
│           │       ProductController.java
│           │
│           └───model
│                   Product.java
│
├───test
└───web
    │   index.html
    │
    ├───css
    │       main.css
    │
    ├───js
    │       functions.js
    │
    └───WEB-INF
        │   glassfish-web.xml
        │
        └───views
                error.jsp
                formProduct.jsp


Take a step back from Java and learn basic SQL first. USER and ORDER are SQL keywords. Either rename your tables or else quote the table names.

index.xhtml is absent, there's index.html. There're not such entities for mapping to USER or ORDER? What is your persistence.xml?

SQL keywords
You have used names that happen to be keywords in some SQL dialects: USER & ORDER.
Over a thousand distinct words have been reserved by various database products. So it is all too easy to collide with your names.
Solutions:

Use quote marks around the names to prevent the words from being interpreted as keywords.
Use different names.

I recommend adding a trailing underscore to every name. The SQL standard specification explicitly promises to never user a trailing underscore in any keyword.



So: USER_ & ORDER_.
Also, the SQL standard requires an implementation to store names in all-uppercase. But every implementation I know of fails to comply. So for maximum portability, use all-lowercase in your names.
So: user_ & order_.

At least Firebird, Derby and Oracle store unquoted identifiers in uppercase.
